# Have Code Change Terminal Settings Upon Load

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-console

I have a program that requires me to enter `chcp 65001` and `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` before I run the code, or it cannot process characters properly. Is there a way to have the code automatically do this upon opening? Its a pain, and easy to forget, to do this every time.

Comment: If you only need to set codepage 65001 for console I/O, then you should use the `win_unicode_console` package instead. The wide-character console API has always worked correctly for both input and output, going back to NT 3.1. OTOH, using codepage 65001 in the legacy codepage API doesn't allow inputting non-ASCII text in any version of Windows, and it's extremely buggy for output prior to Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you should be able to do this within Python, but supposing that its runtime has this requirement, you can do these settings in a batch file before calling python with your script.  For example, suppose this script is called **`pyutf8.bat`** :

```
@echo off
setlocal
chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
python %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

then you could run your script using this:

```
pyutf8 myscript.py
```

The `%1`, etc., are the positional parameters of the script.  You can check if no parameters were given, using that to supply a default parameter.  Something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
if "%1"=="" goto default
python %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
goto :eof
:default
python myscript.py
```

Further reading:

- [Command-line reference A-Z](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)

Comment: Would I be able to set the batch so it then opens my script? I've set a batch file to open two scripts when run, so maybe this is possible?

Comment: Sure - I wrote a general-purpose script, but you could combine things.

Comment: Works like a charm :) many thanks. BTW, what language is this? the @echo off

Comment: That's the Windows batch file (with the extensions introduced in 2000, e.g., the `goto :eof` and `setlocal`).

Comment: Here's a table of [batch commands](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php) showing what was available in DOS, OS/2, and NT. Note that `setlocal` was added to cmd.exe in OS/2 back in the 80s, but extended in NT 4 and Windows 2000.